# Conditional Display <img src=...>

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, conditional-statements, display

I am trying to display some images (directly linked to Google Drive) conditional a previously defined variable's value. 
Would you please help?

I am using jQuery and HTML. 
Here's a sample code of what I'm doing (I removed the actual links):

```
if(roll_payoffpair == 1) {<img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=LINK1"> ;}

if(roll_payoffpair == 2) {<img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=LINK2"> ;}

if(roll_payoffpair == 3) {<img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=LINK3"> ;}
```

Thanks for your help!

I might be confusing something here, as the first comment indicated. I have never used JavaScript, PHP or HTML coding before and now am trying to do some basic stuff for an experimental software.
Not sure how to display those links conditional on a variable. I receive a SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
So I tried to remove the "< >" but got a different SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier.

What I really need, I think, is display a link in HTML. 
using the simple `<img src = " LINK ">` works fine to display a linked image. But how do I do this conditional on a variable in HTML?

Comment: I think you are somehow confusing PHP and Javascript/jQuery (?). Seems like you want to "echo" those `img` tags, but that's not possible in jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. I edited my initial request for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are somehow confusing PHP and Javascript/jQuery (?). It seems like you want to "echo" those img tags, but that's not possible in jQuery/Javascript.

You should put that `img` tag (just *one* tag) into your HTML, give it an ID and change it's `src` attribute via jQuery using the conditions you have, similar to:

```
if(roll_payoffpair == 2) { $("#yourimgID").attr("src", "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=LINK2"); }
```

and similar for the other conditions. The HTLM would be a simple `img` tag containing the used ID:

```
<img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=LINK1" id="yourimgID">
```

Comment: Thank you Johannes. I have no idea what you're suggesting here, but that's because I have never coded in my life. So I am trying to copy your code and use it. I don't get any error messages in the console anymore, so that's some progress! But the browser doesn't show me the image nevertheless. Any idea why that could be? And does it matter how I name the id="yourimgID"? Cheers!

PS: I only used the jQuery code in your post. I suppose that should be displaying the linked picture?

Comment: "I have no idea what you're suggesting here, but that's because I have never coded in my life" - Uh, uh... Sorry, but I think you should learn at least some basic HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery coding before you continue, because there's no way explaining everything if you don't know where to put it and how to connect everything with each other.